# Closed form expression for certain integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $a \leq b$ be real numbers and let $R, p > 0$. Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} (p+1) |x|^p, & |x| \leq R\\
0, & |x| > R \end{cases}
$$I want to compute the integral
$$
I_{r, P}(a, b) = \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. 
$$
Ideally, in as simple of a form as possible, depending on $a, b, r, P$.  I can tell that the answer is $I_{r, P}(a, b) = 0$ whenever $[a, b]$ does not intersect $[-R, R]$, in other words if
$a>R$ or $b < -R$. But is there a simpler, more straightforward answer?

Comment: It will definitely depend on whether $a,b$ are in $(-\infty,-R),$ $[-R,R]$ or $(R,+\infty).$

Comment: Yeah. I was just hoping for a somewhat clean expression. It's certainly easy to compute in the case $[a, b] \subset [0, R]$ or $[a, b] \subset [-R, 0]$. In these cases we have $||b|^{p+1} - |a|^{p+1}|$.

Comment: The indefinite integral is $\operatorname{sgn}(x)|x|^{p+1}=x|x|^p,$ so when $a,b\in[-R,R]$ it will be: $$b|b|^{p}-a|a|^{p}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Doesn't that mean as long as either $a, b \in [-R, R]$ the integral will be $$\min\big\{R^{p+1} - a|a|^p, b|b|^p + R^{p+1}, 2R^{p+1}\big\}$$

Comment: Oops. It should be the min of the above, including $b|b|^p - a|a|^p$.

Comment: My logic: case 1 is $-R \leq a \leq R \leq b$, case 2 is $a \leq -R \leq b \leq R$, case 3 is $a \leq -R \leq R \leq b$, and case 4 (commented above) is $-R \leq a \leq b \leq R$.

Comment: The final case is 0. Which occurs if either $a \leq b \leq -R \leq R$ or $-R \leq R \leq a \leq b$.